# segmentation fault in perl grep function

Tags: perl

working on Euler problem 3

```
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
```

here is my Perl code just try to get all the factors first but it got segmentation fault, my Perl age is just about 2 month, could not figure out why. Segmentation fault 11 when I run it.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use warnings; 
 use strict;

 my $number = 600851475143;
 my @factors = grep {$number % $_ == 0} (1..$number);
 print @factors;
```

Run it again with sudo, no more segmentation fault but nothing printed out.

Comment: Yea, deleted that print code

Comment: `(1..$number)` will generate an 2T array. Are you using a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Yes, Mac OS X 10.8.5, perlbrew Perl 5.18.2. Tried bigint as well, did not make any difference.

Comment: I guess it is still because you are trying to allocate too many memories.

Comment: agreed, even after I removed last 3 digits (so 1000 times smaller). It printed out "Out of Memory!" on my Linux VM, used all my remaining 12G RAM on my MacBook Pro. Will try something else

Comment: Check the stack size allocated to your VM. Using ulimit -s. If the stack segment of any process exceed this stack segment, you will get a segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code from googling "[euler problem 3](http://code.jasonbhill.com/c/project-euler-problem-3/)" and translating the python code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub largest_prime_factor {
    my $n = shift;

    my $largest_factor = 1;

    # remove any factors of 2 first
    while ($n % 2 == 0) {
        $largest_factor = 2;
        $n /= 2;
    }

    # now look at odd factors
    my $p = 3;
    while ($n != 1) {
        while ($n % $p == 0) {
            $largest_factor = $p;
            $n /= $p;
        }
        $p += 2
    }

    return $largest_factor
}

print largest_prime_factor(600851475143);

1;

__END__
```

Or relying on good ole cpan:

```
use Math::Prime::Util qw(factor);
use List::Util qw(max);

use strict;
use warnings;

print max factor(600851475143);
```

Comment: CPAN solution slightly easier now:  perl -E 'use ntheory ":all"; say vecmax(factor(600851475143));'